# C++ Unknown override specifier when using function in callback

Tags: c++, windows

I'm working with C++ and the Windows API now for just a little while. I've never used a callback in C++ since yesterday, when the Windows API required me to do so for installing a low level mouse event hook [(link to hook function)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx). To keep my code a little cleaner I wanted to outsource some code to a function and then I ran into a problem that I don't understand. I think it has to do something with me not totally understanding the callback scope or something like that. My code looks like this and I use C++11 and VS2017:

*MouseHandler.h*

```
#ifndef __MOUSEHANDLER_H_INCLUDED__
#define __MOUSEHANDLER_H_INCLUDED__

#include <Windows.h>

class MouseHandler
{
private:
public:
    static _bstr_t coordinatesToString(POINT point);
MouseHandler();
~MouseHandler();
};
#endif // !__MOUSEHANDLER_H_INCLUDED__
```

*MouseHandler.cpp*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MouseHandler.h"
#include <comutil.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

HHOOK mouseHook = NULL;

_bstr_t MouseHandler::coordinatesToString(POINT point)
{
    _bstr_t coordinates = "(";
    _bstr_t xcoordinate = to_string(point.x).c_str();
    _bstr_t ycoordinate = to_string(point.y).c_str();
    coordinates += xcoordinate + "," + ycoordinate + ")";

    return coordinates;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT event = *((MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam);

    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        _bstr_t message = "Mouse action happened at position: ";
        _bstr_t mouseCoordinates = MouseHandler::coordinatesToString(event.pt);
        message += mouseCoordinates;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(mouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

MouseHandler::MouseHandler()
{
    mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookCallback, NULL, 0);
    while (GetMessage(NULL, NULL, 0, 0) != 0);
}

MouseHandler::~MouseHandler()
{
}
```

When I try to compile I get the error `C3646 'coordinatesToString': unknown override specifier`. I searched up and down and asked my colleagues, but I couldn't get help with this, so I hope someone here can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: at a guess "_bstr_t" isn't defined. what's the full error message and where is it raised (look in the output window not the error list as there is usually more detail)?

Comment: I think what may be happening is that `#include <comutil.h>` should be in the .h file so that that `_bstr_t` is visible for the function declaration.

Comment: @AlanBirtles that was my fault. Thank you! Tried to keep the includes as organized as possible and then theres one that slipped through and caused me such a headache. Would one of you write that as an answer, then I could accept it ;)

Comment: @acraig5075 please read above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you specify the correct type of data.
   `to_string((long double)point.x).c_str();`
2. Load the lib.
   `#pragma comment (lib, "comsuppw.lib")`
   or
   `#pragma comment (lib, "comsuppwd.lib")`
3. Include `comutil.h` to the header `CMouseHandler.h`.

I tested your code in VS2010 C++ on Win10 1803 x64.

---

**CMouseHandler.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib, "comsuppw.lib")

class CMouseHandler
{
public:
    CMouseHandler(void);
    ~CMouseHandler(void);
    static _bstr_t coordinatesToString(POINT point);
};
```

**CMouseHandler.cpp**

```
#include "CMouseHandler.h"

HHOOK mouseHook = NULL;

_bstr_t CMouseHandler::coordinatesToString(POINT point)
{
    _bstr_t coordinates = "(";
    _bstr_t xcoordinate = to_string((long double)point.x).c_str();
    _bstr_t ycoordinate = to_string((long double)point.y).c_str();
    coordinates += xcoordinate + "," + ycoordinate + ")";

    return coordinates;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT event = *((MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam);

    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        _bstr_t message = "Mouse action happened at position: ";
        _bstr_t mouseCoordinates = CMouseHandler::coordinatesToString(event.pt);
        message += mouseCoordinates;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(mouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

CMouseHandler::CMouseHandler()
{
    mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookCallback, NULL, 0);
    while (GetMessage(NULL, NULL, 0, 0) != 0);
}


CMouseHandler::~CMouseHandler(void)
{
}
```

Comment: The only thing that was important was to move the `#include <comutil.h> to the header, the rest is not necessary (in my bigger project). The lib gets included automatically already and why should I have to cast the data that is of that type? But thanks for your answer anyhow :)

Comment: @LSchad Yeah right. I included `comutil.h` to the header. I will add it to my post.

Answer (score 0):

`_bstr_t` isn't defined, as visual studio doesn't recognise the type it assumes its an override specifier. You need to include `comutil.h` as specified in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx).